# PHP separate values by comma

Tags: php, arrays, json, explode

I am trying to separate my JSON Array:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data); ++$i) {
    $mark=explode(',', $data[$i]);
    foreach ($mark as $out) {
        echo $out;
    }
}
```

WHERE

```
    $data = [
        {
            "2":"XXX_or_XX",
            "Left_headlamp":"XXX_or_XX",
            "6":"X, XXX_or_XX, G",
            "Front_glass":"X, XXX_or_XX, G",
            "17":"S2",
            "Right_front_tire":"S2",
            "25":"E3",
            "Left_front_door":"E3",
            "29":"FLS, RRS",
            "Engine_room":"FLS, RRS",
            "30":"6",
            "Stock_id":"6"
        }
    ]
```

What i need is if one column like "Front_glass":"X, XXX_or_XX, G" has three values it should be

```
"Front_glass":"X".
"Front_glass":"XXX_or_XX"  
"Front_glass":" XXX_or_XX"
```

or any thing that is possible Thanks.

Comment: Is `$data` array of strings?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Yes!
array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { [2]=> string(9) "XXX_or_XX" ["Left_headlamp"]=> string(9) "XXX_or_XX" [6]=> string(15) "X, XXX_or_XX, G" ["Front_glass"]=> string(15) "X, XXX_or_XX, G" [17]=> string(2) "S2" ["Right_front_tire"]=> string(2) "S2" [25]=> string(2) "E3" ["Left_front_door"]=> string(2) "E3" [29]=> string(8) "FLS, RRS" ["Engine_room"]=> string(8) "FLS, RRS" [30]=> string(1) "6" ["Stock_id"]=> string(1) "6" } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_map function in your case. Look here [live PHP sandbox](https://phpize.online/?phpses=47d2669df19312066b5d12b010208c19&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

```
foreach($data as $key=>$row) {
    $data[$key] = array_map (
        function($el){
            return explode(',', $el);
        },
        $row
    );
}
```